# Including/excluding columns in MS Access modern charts, programmatically

Tags: vba, ms-access, charts

I have a Microsoft Access modern chart with several query columns included. Some of the columns should be dynamically included or excluded programmatically.
How can I define, include or exclude certain columns from the modern chart?

Comment: Aren't Modern Charts data defined by a RowSource property? Code can set this property.

Comment: I need to preserve design-time formatting for data series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is answered here, by Karl Donaubauer: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-msoffice_custom-mso_2016/includingexcluding-columns-in-ms-access-modern/2d056fad-8eb5-4663-af8b-9774a0514024?tm=1572942297539
RowSource and ChartValues properties have to be set through VBA code, everything else updates automatically, with formatting preserved.